# Algorithm to find a specific result after applying many operation

Tags: algorithm

I need some help to find the best algorithm to solve problems that give you a number from which you start and try to find a specific result after applying many operations.
For exemple if we start from 3 and we can either add 1 or subtract 3 from every result that we obtain until we reach 1.
Which algorithm i can use for theses problems ?

Comment: have you tried the plain old Procedural Programming? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this class of problems by performing [*Breadth-First Search (BFS)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) on an implicitly defined graph:

- Each number reachable by applying zero or more operations represents a vertex,
- Each allowed operation represents an edge.

You record the number of steps that it took you to reach a particular vertex (i.e. a particular sum) in an array, push the initial number onto a queue, along with the number of steps it took to reach it (zero), and proceed with BFS until the queue is drained. At each step you explore all edges one by one, and see if any of the vertices reachable in one step from the current position improve the result that you've got thus far. If they do, push the new position onto the queue; otherwise, proceed to the next edge.

One thing you need to observe with implicit graphs is that they are essentially endless. Therefore, you need to limit them artificially. For example, in case of reaching `23` from `3` by adding `1` or subtracting `3` you could limit your vertices to `[-3..25]` range to avoid going too far from the starting vertex or the target one.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation but i couldn't understand it very well, for example i will take a queue and add to it the start number which is 3, then i make 3 + 1 =4 and 3 - 3 = 0 and add theses 2 numbers to the queue ? and of course put the steps value for 3 is 0 and the steps value for 4 and 0 is 1 ?

Comment: @thechef The queue contains pairs. First element of the pair is vertex (the number). Second element of the pair is the number of steps it takes to reach the vertex. You push `(3, 0)` - start number, zero steps to reach. After that you push `(4, 1)` and `(0, 1)` - `3+1` and `3-3`, both taking one step to reach. Then you push `(5, 2)`, `(1, 2)`, and `(-3, 2)`. You push `(1, 2)` once, even though there are two ways to get to it. After that go `(6, 3)`, `(2, 3)`, and `(-2, 3)`; skip `(-6, 3)` because it is too far out. The next generation is `(7, 4)`, `(-1, 4)` and `(-5, 4)`, and so on.

Comment: Yes thank you again, just one last thing, when i find a pair with the number that i'm trying to reach i exit the BFS ? it will be the best combination of operations no ?

Comment: @thechef Yes, you exit as soon as you reach the target answer, because all other paths queued behind the current one would be as good or inferior.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I understand what you're asking now (and my answer is completely revised).

`n` is the number you are trying to reach minus the number you start with. You need to add 3 `n/3`(using integer division) times, and if `n%3` isn't 0, you need to add another 3 and subtract one `3-(n%3)` times.

Comment: No, i have a given number let's say 5, i must get to 12 but i can just add to my number 3 or substract 1, so i need to fin the best combination of (add 3 or substract 1) to get my result. For this case `5 + 3 + 3 + 3 -1 - 1 = 12`